# Can't connect to local database while using connection string?

Tags: c#, sql-server-express

Here's my connection string

```
Server=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX\SQLExpress;Database=inspection;User Id=sa;Password=xxx;
```

I'm getting an error that it couldn't connect, but when I use connection string like this

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=inspection;User Id=sa;Password=xxx;
```

it connects successfully, I don't know whats problem (the Ip is correct)

Comment: This may be useful http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/

Comment: SQL Server **Express** by default doesn't support remote connections - therefore using an IP address in your connection string won't work. Use `.` or `.\SQLEXPRESS` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If IP address is correct and you have firewall open and other stuff to be able to connect to this IP address, just try using it as is (i.e. without `\SQLExpress` part), so `entServer=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;`

Comment: And configure sql express to listen to the IP address - default config on express IIRC is not to listen to the network externally ;) No TCP enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have enabled the TCP/IP protocol in the SQL Server Configuration Manager, which I believe needs to be enabled for connections that aren't `localhost` (i.e. `.`) to succeed.